# How to read only line coverage from lcov --summary command and store in some shell script variable?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, lcov

When I run the command `lcov --summary coverage/lcov.info`

Im getting the output in the console as below

`Summary coverage rate:
  lines......: 80.5% (4900 of 6090 lines)
  functions..: no data found
  branches...: no data found`

I just want to save the line coverage 80.5 in some variable.
So wrote a bash script `UTreport.sh` file

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
report = "$(lcov --summary coverage/lcov.info)"
echo The value of the report $report`

but this script file throws an error.

`UTreport.sh: line 2: report: command not found
The value of the report`

is there any way to get this value?

Comment: No spaces on the variable assignment, you can try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: thank you.it's working.